# Use a reactive property coming from a composition function on a SFC in Nuxt 2 using @nuxtjs/composition-api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So I'm trying to figure out this composition function. What I want to do is to use the "filters" object coming from the composition function into a SFC (without worrying about it's hierarchy in the DOM tree), at the moment when importing the composition function into my component and trying to use the "filters" object in my template I always get an empty object even when I see that is updating in another components:

Here's the composition function called "useCastingParams.ts"

```
import { needsToFetch } from '~/utils/needsToFetch';
import { reactive, watch, computed, ssrPromise, SetupContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import countriesJson from '~/assets/js/data/countries.json';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
import findKey from 'lodash/findKey';
import gendersJson from '~/assets/js/data/genders.json';
import jobTypesJson from '~/assets/js/data/jobTypes.json';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import paymentsJson from '~/assets/js/data/payments.json';
import useAuth from '~/utils/useAuth';
import useConfig from '~/utils/useConfig';
import useI18n from '~/utils/useI18n';
import useRouter from '~/utils/useRouter';
import useStore from '~/utils/useStore';

export type CastingFilters = {
    gender?: string;
    type?: string;
    country_iso?: string;
    city?: string;
    state?: string;
    payment?: string;
    order?: string;
};

type Option<Data = any> = {
    title: string;
    value?: string | number;
    data?: Data;
};

const useCastingsParams = (context: SetupContext) => {
    const { router, route } = useRouter(context);
    const i18n = useI18n(context);
    const auth = useAuth(context);
    const { appUrl, translatedLanguages } = useConfig(context);

    const {
        actions: { fetch: fetchCities },
        state: cityData,
    } = useStore(context, 'castings/castingCities');
    const {
        actions: { fetch: fetchCountries },
        state: countries,
    } = useStore(context, 'countries');

    const filters = reactive<{
        gender?: string;
        type?: string;
        country_iso?: string;
        city?: string;
        state?: string;
        payment?: string;
        order?: string;
    }>({
        gender: undefined,
        type: undefined,
        country_iso: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        state: undefined,
        payment: undefined,
        order: undefined,
    });
    const filterOptions: {
        key: keyof typeof filters;
        options: { [key: string]: { label: string; value: string } };
    }[] = [
        {
            options: gendersJson,
            key: 'gender',
        },
        {
            options: countriesJson,
            key: 'country_iso',
        },
        {
            options: paymentsJson,
            key: 'payment',
        },
        {
            options: jobTypesJson,
            key: 'type',
        },
    ];

    const isParamInOptions = (param: string) => {
        return filterOptions.some((filter) => {
            return !!filter.options[param];
        });
    };

    const getUrlParamFromFilter = (
        filter: string | undefined,
        json: { [key: string]: { label: string; value: string } },
    ) => findKey(json, { value: filter });

    const handleFilterChange = (id: keyof typeof filters, value: string) => {
        filters[id] = value;
    };

    const handleFilterResetAll = (values: [keyof typeof filters, any][]) => {
        values.forEach(([id, defaultValue]) => {
            filters[id] = defaultValue;
        });
    };

    ssrPromise(() => {
        if (needsToFetch(countries)) {
            return fetchCountries({ options: { context } });
        }
    }, 'fetchCountries');

    const areProToolsAllowed = computed(() => {
        return auth.loggedIn && auth.user.subscription_plan_name !== '';
    });

    const canonicalHref = computed(() => {
        const countrySlug =
            filters.country_iso && findKey(countriesJson, (c) => c === filters.country_iso);
        const includeJobType = !filters.gender && !countrySlug && !filters.city && !filters.state;
        // Any language which is not translated fully or (<90%) should have a canonical to the English URL
        const includeLanguage =
            translatedLanguages.includes(i18n.locale) && i18n.locale !== i18n.defaultLocale;

        const urlParts = [
            appUrl,
            includeLanguage && i18n.locale,
            'castings',
            getUrlParamFromFilter(filters.gender, gendersJson),
            countrySlug,
            filters.city,
            filters.state,
            includeJobType && getUrlParamFromFilter(filters.type, jobTypesJson),
        ];

        return `${urlParts.filter((p) => !!p).join('/')}/`;
    });

    const cityOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        if (filters.country_iso) {
            const { cities } = cityData[filters.country_iso].data;
            return cities.map((c: ListCity) => ({
                title: c.name,
                value: c.slug,
                data: c,
            }));
        }

        return [];
    });

    const countryOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        return map(countries.data, (c: Country) => ({
            title: c.name,
            value: c.iso,
            data: c,
        }));
    });

    const filterHash = computed(() => {
        return route.value.fullPath.replace(`/${i18n.locale}/`, '/');
    });

    const genderOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        return map(gendersJson, (gender) => {
            return {
                title: i18n.t(gender.label) as string,
                value: gender.value,
            };
        });
    });

    const jobTypeOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        return map(jobTypesJson, (jobType) => {
            return {
                title: i18n.t(jobType.label) as string,
                value: jobType.value,
            };
        });
    });

    const orderOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        return [
            {
                title: i18n.t('castings.filters.order.recent') as string,
                value: undefined,
            },
            {
                title: i18n.t('castings.filters.order.expiration') as string,
                value: 'expiration',
            },
        ];
    });

    const paymentOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        return map(paymentsJson, (payment) => {
            return {
                title: i18n.t(payment.label) as string,
                value: payment.value,
            };
        });
    });

    const selectedFilters = computed(() => {
        return [
            {
                id: 'gender',
                value: filters.gender,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return genderOptions.value.find((g) => g.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'type',
                value: filters.type,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return jobTypeOptions.value.find((t) => t.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'country_iso',
                value: filters.country_iso,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return countryOptions.value.find((c) => c.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'state',
                value: filters.state,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return stateOptions.value.find((c) => c.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'city',
                value: filters.city,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return cityOptions.value.find((c) => c.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'payment',
                value: filters.payment,
                defaultValue: undefined,
                formatter: (v: string) => {
                    return paymentOptions.value.find((p) => p.value === v)?.title;
                },
            },
        ];
    });

    const stateOptions = computed<Option[]>(() => {
        if (filters.country_iso) {
            const { states } = cityData[filters.country_iso].data;
            return states.map((c: ListCity) => ({
                title: c.name,
                value: c.slug,
                data: c,
            }));
        }

        return [];
    });

    // Set filter according to url
    watch(
        route,
        (newRoute) => {
            const { params, query } = newRoute;

            const paramsArray = Object.values(params);

            for (let paramsIndex = 0; paramsIndex < paramsArray.length; paramsIndex++) {
                const param = paramsArray[paramsIndex];

                for (let filterIndex = 0; filterIndex < filterOptions.length; filterIndex++) {
                    const filter = filterOptions[filterIndex];

                    if (filter.options[param]) {
                        if (filter.key === 'country_iso') {
                            // @ts-ignore
                            filters[filter.key] = filter.options[param];

                            // City or State
                            // If the next param after country is not in JSONs, we asume it's the city or state
                            const nextParam = paramsArray[paramsIndex + 1] as string;
                            if (nextParam && !isParamInOptions(nextParam)) {
                                if (nextParam.includes('-state')) {
                                    filters.state = nextParam;
                                    const afterParam = paramsArray[paramsIndex + 2] as string;
                                    if (afterParam && !isParamInOptions(afterParam)) {
                                        filters.city = afterParam;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    filters.city = nextParam;
                                }
                                paramsIndex++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (
                                areProToolsAllowed.value ||
                                (filter.key !== 'payment' && filter.key !== 'type')
                            ) {
                                filters[filter.key] = filter.options[param].value;
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            filters.order = query.order?.toString();
        },
        {
            immediate: true,
        },
    );

    watch(
        () => filters.country_iso,
        (country, oldCountry) => {
            if (country && needsToFetch(cityData[country])) {
                fetchCities({ options: { context }, countryISO: country });
            }

            if (!country || (oldCountry && country !== oldCountry)) {
                filters.city = undefined;
                filters.state = undefined;
            }
        },
        {
            immediate: true,
            deep: true,
        },
    );

    watch(
        () => filters.state,
        (state, oldState) => {
            if (state) {
                fetchCities({
                    options: { context },
                    countryISO: filters.country_iso,
                    state: state,
                });
            }

            if (!state || (oldState && state !== oldState)) {
                filters.city = undefined;
            }
        },
        {
            immediate: true,
            deep: true,
        },
    );

    // Change url when filters change
    watch(
        filters,
        debounce((f) => {
            const countrySlug = f.country_iso && countries.data[f.country_iso].en_slug;
            const newPath = context.root.localePath({
                name: 'castings',
                params: {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    filter1: getUrlParamFromFilter(f.gender, gendersJson),
                    filter2: countrySlug,
                    filter3: f.state,
                    filter4: f.city,
                    // @ts-ignore
                    filter5: getUrlParamFromFilter(f.payment, paymentsJson),
                    // @ts-ignore
                    filter6: getUrlParamFromFilter(f.type, jobTypesJson),
                },
                query: {
                    order: f.order,
                },
            });
            if (newPath !== route.value.fullPath) {
                router.replace(newPath);
            }
        }, 10),
    );

    return {
        filters,
        filterHash,
        options: {
            gender: genderOptions,
            country: countryOptions,
            city: cityOptions,
            state: stateOptions,
            jobType: jobTypeOptions,
            payment: paymentOptions,
            order: orderOptions,
        },
        selectedFilters,
        handleFilterChange,
        handleFilterResetAll,
        canonicalHref,
    };
};

export default useCastingsParams;
```

The important part for me is the watcher that looks for changes in the filters object (the one with the "// Change url when filters change" comment) since I want to use the filters object to re-direct the user (using those filters into the url) to a new page. Here's a short version of the SFC where I'm trying to print the filters object in my template:

```
<template>
<h2>Filters: {{ filters.gender }}</h2>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
    computed,
    defineComponent,
    ref,
    useAsync,
    useMeta,
    useRoute,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import useCastingsParams from '~/components/Pages/Casting/useCastingsParams';
export default defineComponent({
const { filters } = useCastingsParams(context);
return {
    filters
}
    },
});
</script>
```

At the moment I'm getting an empty string and I can see that the reactive object updates itself when used into another components.